# Convert dd/MM/yyyy to yyyy/MM/dd?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to convert a string '30/12/2012' to '2012/12/30'. My application is set to "en-CA" however the database accepts yyyy/MM/dd as default.

> How can I do this without depending on the current culture info set
>   at server?

Comment: The database accepts a string-converted date value instead of the actual date value?

Comment: The database has a date column with default format 'yyyy/MM/dd'

Comment: And what is the data type of the date column? Varchar?

Comment: Can you post the code that sends the date to your database?

Comment: It is currently string in the Business object & date in database.

Comment: @DamienJoe Eww. If possible I would promote it to a DateTime/DateTimeOffset in the BO as well... if you keep it as DateTime you can either pass it to the DB as a DateTime (better) or use a simple "yyyy/MM/dd" format string (at *one* spot).

Comment: why not use DateTime in your business object ?

Comment: If the data type is Date in the database, you don't have to convert it to a string in the code behind. Create a `DateTime` object from the string input, create a parameter for your SQL(?) stored procedure/script, and specify in your parameter that the value is DateTime.

Comment: I've attempted to capture the thrust of these comments (which I entirely agree with) in my answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As all the comments have said, but none of the answers have said so far: *don't pass this to the database as a string*.

Parse any text you receive as early as possible, then use `DateTime` to represent it *everywhere* else, including how you send it to the database, via parameterized SQL<sup>1</sup>. This goes for values of all kinds: convert it *into* the "natural" type for the data as soon as possible, and keep it in that natural representation for as long as possible. A date isn't a string, and you should only convert it to a string if you really, really need to - ideally *just* before displaying it to a user.

The parsing can be done with `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` depending on whether this is "suspicious" data (e.g. from a user) or data which should *really* be correct and for which an exception is the most appropriate reaction to unparseable values. I suggest you pass in `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` with your custom format string. For example:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(text, "dd/MM/yyyy",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

(If you do a lot of date/time work, you may also want to consider using my [Noda Time project](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) which allows you to express the value in a richer way - in this case you'd probably use `LocalDate`.)

---

<sup>1</sup> If you're not already using parameterized SQL, but are instead baking values directly into the SQL, you have bigger problems than date/time conversions.

Comment: That was an most excellent piece of advice Jon. It took me a day to correct the business object & data access layer but it was worth the effort. I did exactly as you advised & now I have no conversion errors which were poppin up here & there frequently. Thumbs up for the excellent advise & I loved the discussion here, Damein =)

Comment: @DamienJoe: Excellent - so glad it worked out for you. The whole principle of sticking with the most natural representation for as long as possible has become quite dear to me.

Answer (score 4):

You can specify CultureInfo in Format and most ToString functions.

I.e. [DateTime.ToString(CultureInfo)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht77y576.aspx) and [DateTime.Parse(string, CultureInfo)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs) will let you pars string in one culture (i.e. current or `new CultureInfo("en-CA")`) and format with another like `new CultureInfo("en-us")`.

Note: you may consider running all DB access under some other culture (i.e. `en-US`) by setting Thread.CurrentCulture as sometimes number fomats are also impacted (if numbers are storead as string).

Answer (score 4):

If its going to always be in the same format. Then split it on the `/` character

```
string[] tempsplit = datestring.Split('/');
```

and then put it back together

```
string joinstring = "/";
string newdate = tempsplit[2] + joinstring + tempsplit[1] + joinstring + tempsplit[0];
```

simple.

Comment: This will result in an out-of-bound exception. Had you used `Split('/')` (with an upper case S), it would have resulted in `"20120620"`. Honestly, I almost always test code I post publicly.

Comment: Yes, I totally see where you're going here `:)`

Comment: perhaps  datestring.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Comment: Why would you do this manually (accepting invalid data, e.g. month 20) rather than parsing then reformatting using `DateTime`?

Answer (score 2):

First convert your string to DateTime format using

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("your string value");
```

Then save it in string using:

```
string st=dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

This will convert your date format to any desired format you want without depending on culture

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime` *does* depend on the culture. How else is it going to understand what (say) 05/06/2012 means? Is that May 6th or June 5th? (Your `ToString` call also depends on the culture for the date separator.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet I agree to your point but in question he wants a solution that converts any of the DateTime format into desired one and there should be no need to mention culture info

For that part only I have written following line:
This will convert your date format to any desired format you want without depending on culture

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work.

```
        var x = new string[] { "2012/06/12", "20/06/2012", "111/111/1111" };
        foreach (var ds in x)
        {
            DateTime d = default(DateTime);
            try
            {
                d = DateTime.Parse(ds, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-CA"));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                try
                {
                    d = DateTime.ParseExact(ds, "yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
            if (d == default(DateTime))
                Console.WriteLine("error");
            else
                Console.WriteLine(d.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Your variable x is already in the format I wanted. I tried this but it did not work for me with '20/06/2012'.

Comment: Just edited the code. It is ugly. you might consider TryParse() method.

Comment: Thanks for your code dan_I. Although I took Jon Skeets advise but I did use your code as reference on my data layer. The only catch was that the input string must be in the same format as speficied. +1

Answer (score 1):

Without going into the issue what format the database accepts or not, you can do the conversion like this:

- Convert the String to Datetime like [explained here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14743/Easy-String-to-DateTime-DateTime-to-String-and-For)
- Change the format and convert it to string again like [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format)