# How to convert AjaxCalendar extender Textbox Date input to SqlServer Date input

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ajax, datetime

I have a following table schema in my SqlServer Database.

```
COLUMN_NAME       DATA_TYPE
Application_Date  date
```

My_Table

```
ID  Application_Date Employee_Name
1    2014-05-16        a
2    2014-05-26        b
```

I am trying to search few data between those date datatypes from My_Table using a Button_Click() event and bind the data in my JQGrid.
I have created dynamic web controls like two text boxes with AjaxCalendarExtender respectively.

**How to convert the text box date input to SqlServer Date input inorder to provide input for my SQL Injection present inside the Search Button_Click() event.**

My C# code:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel2.Visible = true;
        JQGrid10.Visible = true;

        try
        {

            Table maintable = form1.FindControl("dynamic_filter_table_id") as Table;
            int rc = maintable.Rows.Count;
            if (rc == 1)
            {
                try
                {

                    if (D1.SelectedValue.Contains("datetime"))
                    {
                        TextBox T1 = maintable.FindControl("DateFrom") as TextBox;
                        TextBox T2 = maintable.FindControl("DateTo") as TextBox;

                        DateTime inputone;
                        DateTime inputtwo;
                        inputone = DateTime.Parse(T1.Text);
                        inputtwo = DateTime.Parse(T2.Text);

                        **//How to parse for SqlServer Date datatype format **

                        SqlDataAdapter sql = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT A.Col1,B.Employee_Name,B.Application_Date,B.ID, FROM RESULT as B, EMPLOYEE as A WHERE B.Application_Date Between " + inputone + " AND " + inputtwo, connectionstring);

                        DataSet data = new DataSet();
                        sql.Fill(data);
                        con.Close();
                        Session["DataforSearch_DDL"] = data.Tables[0];
                    }
                }

                catch
                {
                    NotImplementedException();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: it seems you are checking Employee_Name `B.Employee_Name Between " + inputone + " AND " + inputtwo, connectionstring` not the date.

Comment: @ Himanshu : oops. made a typo. changed my sql injection query order

Comment: What is your actual problem, any error you get??

Comment: try this `WHERE B.Application_Date  Between '" + inputone + "' AND '" + inputtwo +"'`. don't use `,` after `B.Application_Date`

Comment: @Himanshu i removed the comma. Let me try this out. But the textbox input is given in this dd/MM/yyyy and will / create a conflict ? as sqlserver has YYYY-MM-DD format

Comment: try to change format, for e.g `DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(inputone);
string st=dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`

Comment: [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113301/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-to-yyyy-mm-dd) for more date conversion example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to make use of SqlCommand.Parameters.

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand(connectionstring);
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT A.Col1,B.Application_Date,B.ID, FROM RESULT as B, EMPLOYEE as A WHERE B.Application_Date, B.Employee_Name Between @inputone AND @inputtwo";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@inputone", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = inputone;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@inputtwo", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = inputtwo;
```

Comment: I don't need the time input. only the Date input. I am using SqlDataAdapter as a Datasource for my JQGrid.

Comment: @Shrivatsan You're missing the point. You need to take advantage of parameterization in order to prevent SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: @MASON ok i will take a note of it.